# Laravel chunk a collection in Blade with custom order

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Trying to write the cleanest code in Blade of a foreach where in the position 3 (if first and second exists) add a different code.

I'm trying using chunk() but it doesnt allow do non regulars array.

- Write position 1 if exists
- Write position 2 if exists with different class
- Write some content between array position 2 and 3 from different array
- Write position 3 if exists
- Write position 4 if exists with different class
- ...

Answer (score 1):

why u use chunk? u can use $key

```
@foreach($arr as $key => $value)
@if ($key === 2)
  do something
@endif
@endforeach
```

or

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
@if ($i === 2)
  do something
@endif
@endfor
```